# Shabbat Amidah, which parts

Tags: halacha, shabbat, shemoneh-esrei

I am following a wonderful audio to learn the Amidah. It is [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/980653/jewish/Audio.htm) on Chabad.

I come from an almost non-religious Jewish family and don't really know which prayers to do and so I am following this. However I cannot figure out what to do on evening Shabbat. I know that the middle is left out but I am not sure what defines the middle in the audio. Can anyone tell me?

Also, is this same version of the Amidah to be used for morning, evening, and afternoon? I read that the Amidah should be done 3 times a day during the week.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Jen. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 7):

Indeed one prays the amida three times a day (four times on Shabbat and holidays), once in the evening (*arvit*) since the Jewish  day goes from evening to evening, once in the morning (*shaharit*) and once in the afternoon (*minha*). See [here](https://www.chabad.org/calendar/zmanim_cdo/jewish/Halachic-Times.htm) if you are interested in the exact times (definitions are [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/134527/jewish/Zmanim-Briefly-Defined-and-Explained.htm#shema)).

During the week it is nearly the same *amida* prayer between morning, afternoon and evening but on Shabbat it is a different version. The Shabbat *amida* has the same first three and last three blessings, but only has one blessing in the middle (making it seven blessings instead of nineteen during the week).

You would need a prayer book (*siddur*) to properly learn and understand the differences. If you don't yet read Hebrew, you can get a transliterated siddur (e.g., [here](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578191512.html) from artscroll for weekdays, [here](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578191505.html) for Shabbat and holidays). And [this](http://siddur.org/) appears to be a transliterated online siddur (Friday night [here](http://siddur.org/transliterations/friday-night-sabbath-services/shabbat-maariv-amidah#prologue)).

There is also a version of the Shabbat amida on Sefaria, [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Shabbat%2C_Maariv%2C_Amidah%2C_Patriarchs?lang=bi) for Friday night, [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Shabbat%2C_Shacharit%2C_Amidah%2C_Patriarchs?lang=bi) for Saturday morning.

Of course, nothing beats joining a real Jewish community and asking someone to help you through prayers. Contacting the rabbi in advance is always a good idea so he can pair you up with a friendly congregant. To prepare, take a look at [this introduction](https://njop.org/resources/shabbat/learn-about-shabbat-services/) to the Shabbat service from [NJOP](https://njop.org/), incidentally they run [beginner services](https://njop.org/partners/programs/shabbat-beginners-service/) in many synagogues where thousands have learned to pray.

Good luck on the journey, welcome to Mi Yodeya and don't hesitate to ask here for further questions.

Comment: Wow, wow, wow! Thanks! I have been looking around for the Friday night version with audio. Thank you for the online site. Baruch Hashem!!! I have a Siddur but honestly the print is so small I have trouble reading it. Also, I don't really get which parts to do. I have one that has translation into English along with the hebrew. I can't read hebrew anymore. I guess I could when I was 13. I have a Siddur published by Otsar Sifrei Lubavtch. I am not anywhere near a shul. I live in Asia and the closest one is about 7 hours away :(

Comment: @Jen there is a free program called "Partners in Torah" that will match you up with a learning partner over the internet. I highly reccomend it (I myself live in a remote part of South America and so know what you're going through being far from a Jewish community) https://www.partnersintorah.org

Comment: @Jen issue with an online version is that you cannot use it on Shabbat. It is better to give up on the prayer than transgress Shabbat by reading it online. Both amazon and artscroll will ship you a siddur wherever you are (hoping it is not North Korea :->) Also you can pray in English until you become comfortable again with the Hebrew. Best of luck